# Replace rows where a column is an empty string, but not where there is already data?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to add 2500 rows of data to a table of labels and their translations.
For some labels we already have translations in the table, I would like to keep those translations as they are made manually and more likely to be correct. However wherever there is no translation in place I would like to add the new one I got.

How the database looks like:

```
Lan locale  label   translation
ar  es_AR   Crane   
bg  bg_BG   Crane   
cs  cs_CZ   Crane   
de  de_DE   Crane   Ladekran
ee  et_EE   Crane   
el  el_GR   Crane   
en  en_GB   Crane   Crane
es  es_ES   Crane   Grúa
fr  fr_FR   Crane   Grue
hr  hr_HR   Crane   
hu  hu_HU   Crane   
it  it_IT   Crane   Gru
lt  lt_LT   Crane   
lv  lv_LV   Crane   
nl  nl_NL   Crane   Laadkraan
pl  pl_PL   Crane   Dźwig
pt  pt_PT   Crane   Guindaste
ro  ro_RO   Crane   Macara
ru  ru_RU   Crane   
sk  sk_SK   Crane   
tr  tr_TR   Crane   
uk  uk_UA   Crane   
xk  sq_XK   Crane
```

This is the translations I have for the same label:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO translation
(`lan`,`locale`,`label`,`translation`)
 VALUES
('en','en_GB','crane','Crane')
('nl','nl_NL','crane','Kraan')
('de','de_DE','crane','Kran')
('ru','ru_RU','crane','Подъёмный кран')
('es','es_ES','crane','Grúa')
('fr','fr_FR','crane','Grue')
('hr','hr_HR','crane','Kran')
('it','it_IT','crane','Gru')
('pl','pl_PL','crane','Dźwig')
('pt','pt_PT','crane','Grua')
('ro','ro_RO','crane','Macara')
('bg','bg_BG','crane','Кран')
('ar','es_AR','crane','رافعة')
```

Ideally i would like to add the BG, HR, HU, RU translation. And keep the (for example DE) translations which are already in place.Is there any way this is feasible?

Comment: Could you please elaborate more, if i am not wrong you want to update the rows where there is no transalation, and ignore those having translation.

Comment: Hi Naveem, you're correct. I do want to update the rows where there is no translation, so where the column translation is ''. But also I want to insert rows when the row with the label and language combination is missing. And finally when there is already a translation, I would like to keep that translation and not use the new one I have.

Answer (score 1):

One of the solution is to store the records which need to be inserted in a temp table.

then join this table with the original table and run an insert and update query with the join.

In the following way:

```
INSERT INTO translation_temp
(`lan`,`locale`,`label`,`translation`)
 VALUES
('en','en_GB','crane','Crane')
('nl','nl_NL','crane','Kraan')
('de','de_DE','crane','Kran')
('ru','ru_RU','crane','Подъёмный кран')
('es','es_ES','crane','Grúa')
('fr','fr_FR','crane','Grue')
('hr','hr_HR','crane','Kran')
('it','it_IT','crane','Gru')
('pl','pl_PL','crane','Dźwig')
('pt','pt_PT','crane','Grua')
('ro','ro_RO','crane','Macara')
('bg','bg_BG','crane','Кран')
('ar','es_AR','crane','رافعة');
```

After inserting into another table.

Now our first step will be to add the missing rows, for this we can have a left join in following way,

```
INSERT INTO translation 
SELECT
tempo.lan, tempo.locale, tempo.label, tempo.translation
translation_temp ttemp
LEFT JOIN
translation torg
ON
torg.lan = ttemp.lan
AND
torg.locale = tempo.locale
AND
torg.label = tempo.label
WHERE
torg.lan IS NULL
# TO find there is no row for that temp table row in our original table
```

Now we can just update the values of the column from join where translation is blank in original table

```
UPDATE
translation torg
INNER JOIN
translation_temp ttemp
ON
torg.lan = ttemp.lan
AND
torg.locale = tempo.locale
AND
torg.label = tempo.label
SET
torg.translation = tempo.translation
WHERE
torg.translation IS NULL OR torg.translation = ''
```

This should work, it depends in what scenario this needed to be done, for one time process you could create a migration script for this query, and for using multiple times you need to create SP for this procedure is that this could be reused.

Note :

For missing elements we are using LEFT JOIN

For updating data we are using INNER JOIN